# Arrow Operator vs. Dot Operator

Tags: c, pointers, structure

It seems to me that C's arrow operator (->) is unnecessary. The dot operator (.) should be sufficient. Take the following code:

```
typedef struct {
    int member;
} my_type;

my_type   foo;
my_type * bar;
int       val;

val = foo.member;
val = bar->member;
```

We see that the arrow operator must be used to dereference bar. However, I would prefer to write

```
val = bar.member;
```

There is no ambiguity as to whether I am trying to pull 'member' from a structure or from a pointer to the structure. But it is easy to use the wrong operator, especially when refactoring code. (For example, maybe I am doing some complex operations on foo, so I move the code into a new function and pass a pointer to foo). I don't think I need to care whether foo is a pointer or not; the compiler can worry about the details.

So the question: wouldn't it be simpler to eliminate -> from the C language?

Comment: There are billions of lines of C code in use today.  It wouldn't be simple to remove anything from the C language.  That said, explicitness about indirection is A Good Thing.

Comment: You're right, it is unnecessary. It is syntactic sugar for `(*bar).member`. By definition, we don't _need_ any syntactic sugar. Then again, we don't _need_ functions, either. we _could_ just do everything with `goto`.

Comment: Yes, but it seems like syntactic sugar which makes things harder rather than easier. Functions, on the other hand, are handy. :)

Comment: @jpm: What about recursive calls? Note that even BASIC had `GOSUB`, and processors have `call` instructions.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does the arrow (->) operator in C exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13366083/3425536).

Comment: In the Rust programming language, the `.` operator dereferences as many layers of pointers as needed before accessing the struct field. It does exactly what you're asking for in this thread.

Comment: Due to `*` and `.` precedence, you have to write `(*(*(*a).b).c).d` for `a->b->c->d`. I prefer the readabilty of the second

Answer (score 96):

The 'arrow' operator is syntactic sugar.  `bar->member` is the same as `(*bar).member`.  One reason for the difference is maintainability.  With the arrow operator distinct from the dot operator, it becomes much easier to keep track of which variables are pointers and which are not.  It might be possible to always use `.` and have the compiler try to do the right thing, but I doubt that would make the language simpler.  Trusting the compiler to interpret what you *meant* instead of what you *literally wrote* usually turns out badly.

Comment: Not to mention classes that act like pointers (providing `*` and `->` operators), but on which `.` is also a valid operation.

Comment: @jpm: C does not have classes. However you have a point insofar as this would introduce a needless incompatibility to C++ (which for the reason you state would probably not adopt that convention).

Comment: If `member` is itself a struct, does this equivalence between `(*).` and `→` still apply?  e.g. `bar→member→value` is the same as `(*bar).member→value`, but `bar→(*member).value` is different (in fact, it gives a compile error).

Comment: @MaxCoplan If `member` is a struct, you can't apply the `*` *or* `->` operators to it. Both `bar->member->value` and `(*bar).member->value` are equivalently wrong.  The only correct ways to do it would be `bar->member.value` or `(*bar).member.value`.

Comment: @bta My bad! I meant if `member` is a pointer to another struct. So, ASSUMING `bar→member→value` is valid, `(*bar).member→value` will also work, but `bar→(*member).value` and `(*bar).(*member).value` will be different.

Comment: @MaxCoplan Yes the two forms are still equivalent, but operator precedence quickly makes things quite ugly and error-prone (`.` and `->` bind higher than `*`).  `a->b->c` would become `(*(*a).b).c`.  You really don't want to write this out the long way in a multi-level scenario.

Comment: Explained perfectly, thanks

Comment: (P.S. for [further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13366476/6100005))

Answer (score 9):

No, it would *not* be easier to eliminate `->` from the language, for the simple reason that megatons of code would have to be rewritten if it were. However one *could* define that `p.x` is equivalent to `p->x` if `p` is a pointer. That would be a backwards-compatible change because that code is currently illegal.

Comment: Yes, but as @bta mentions, it would be an unwise change. `->` helps significantly in determining which variables are values and which are pointers, which in turn can help keep memory management maintainable.