# Why does C have both . and -> for addressing struct members?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the arrow (->) operator in C exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366083/why-does-the-arrow-operator-in-c-exist)

Why does C have both *.* and *->* for addressing struct members?

Is it possible to have such modified language syntax, where we can take *p* as a pointer to struct and get a struct member's value just as *p.value*?

Comment: The `->` is used to dereference pointers.

Comment: `ptr->member` is equiv to `(*ptr).member`, if that helps at all, and to answer your ending-question, No.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c?lq=1 (for C++, but the answer is the same)

Comment: OK, so -> is seems a kind of syntax sugar, but why it's still impossible to apply dot to pointer on a syntax level?

Comment: it happens to be a hot topic of last week.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366083/why-does-the-arrow-operator-in-c-exist

Answer (score 3):

From the C99 Spec.

The first operand of the `.` operator shall have a qualified or unqualified structure or union
type, and the second operand shall name a member of that type.

The first operand of the `->` operator shall have type **pointer to qualified or unqualified
structure** or **pointer to qualified or unqualified union**, and the second operand shall
name a member of the type pointed to.

My guess is, for identification purpose they used two operators for member access. i.e for pointer type struct variable is `->` and `.` for ordinary struct variable.

For example:

```
struct sample E, *E1;
```

the expression `(&E)->MOS` is the same as `E.MOS` and 
 `(*E1).MOS` is the same as `E1->MOS`

Answer (score 3):

You can think of `p->m` as shorthand for `(*p).m`

Answer (score 2):

**Is it possible?** Yes. The syntax is as follows:

```
(*ptr).member
```

The parentheses are required because the *structure member operator* `.` has higher precedence than the *indirection operator* `*`. But after using that a few times you will agree that the following is easier to use:

```
ptr->member
```

**Why does C have both?** Pointers to structures are used so often in C that a special operator was created, called the *structure pointer operator* `->`. It's job is to more clearly and conveniently express pointers to structures.

Answer (score 0):

. is for struct variable, and -> is for pointer. If p is a pointer, you can do p->value or (*p).value, they are same.

Comment: OK, but what's wrong to have p.value in language syntax?

Comment: p.value only works when p is a struct variable. Compiler will check what p is. If p is a pointer, and you use p->value, then compile will give you error.

Comment: it's not a _must_ that `.` should be used for "struct variable", there's unions.