# '->' operator in C and how it's used

Tags: c, pointers, structure

**EDIT - updated with 2-star pointer for more relevancy**

Say I had a two-star pointer to a structure that also contained a pointer.

```
typedef struct{
    nodeT *ptr;
}nodeT; 

nodeT example; 
nodeT *test1 = &example;
nodeT *test = &test1;
```

If I wanted the address of the pointer in the structure, what would the syntax be?
I tried this:

```
&(*test->ptr)
```

Where it was a thought that the parethesis would reduce to the actual pointer, after which the & operator is used to return the address.

Rather, I found this to be the correct syntax by trial and error:

```
&(*test)->ptr;
```

---

Further, I was confused why the below syntax does not work to even dereference the `test` pointer to the structure pointer:

```
*test->ptr;
```

It was my experience that without the parenthesis around `*test` the compiler returned a statement informing me I was attempting to access something not a part of a structure or union.

It must have something to do with the priority assigned to the various format elements that I am not fully aware.

Any ideas?

Comment: Reading up on [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) should make this clearer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the arrow (->) operator in C exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13366083/1281433).  The question's not quite the same, but the description of how `->` works, why it's there, etc., should more or less answer this question.

Comment: Sorry, made a few edits. To be more specific, my problem was with the use of two-star pointers as the edits show.

Comment: The code doesn't compile in C; you can't use `nodeT *ptr;` in the structure.  You'd need `typedef struct nodeT nodeT; struct nodeT { nodeT *ptr; };`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix operators such as the `.` and `->` component selection operators have higher precedence than unary `*` and `&`.  Thus, `*foo->bar` will be interpreted as `*(foo->bar)`; the `*` operator will be applied to the result of `foo->bar`.  Similarly, `&bar.foo` will be interpreted as `&(bar.foo)`.

So, given the following declarations:

```
nodeT example;
nodeT *test1 = &example;
nodeT **test2 = &test1;
```

you would access the `ptr` member as follows:

1. `example.ptr` - The subexpression `example` has type `nodeT`; no indirection is required, so we simply use the `.` component selection operator;
2. `test1->ptr` - The subexpression `test1` has type `nodeT *`; there's one level of indirection, so we need to *dereference* `test1` before we can access the `ptr` member.  We do that by either using the `->` operator (which implicitly deferences `test1`), or we can *explicitly* dereference `test1` ourselves and write `(*test1).ptr`.
3. `(*test2)->ptr` - The subexpression `test2` has type `nodeT **`; there are two levels of indirection, so we need to dereference `test2` *twice* before we can access the `ptr` member.  We need to explicitly dereference it once if we want to use the `->` operator, or we dereference it twice to use the `.` operator - `(**test2).ptr`.

You use the `.` component selection operator if the left-hand operand is a `struct` or `union` type, such as `example` or `(*test1)` or `(**test2)`.  You use the `->` operator if the left-hand operand is a *pointer* to a `struct` or `union` type, such as `test1` or `(*test2)`.

Now for the real fun - the `ptr` member has type `nodeT *`, so if you want to get the `ptr` that `example.ptr` points to, you would write `example.ptr->ptr`.  The subexpression `example` has type `nodeT`, so we used the `.` component selection operator with it.  The subexpression `example.ptr`, however, has type `nodeT *`, so we'd need to use the `->` component selection operator for it.  Alternately, we'd have to write `(*example.ptr).ptr` (remember, `*example.ptr` is parsed as `*(example.ptr)`).

Going one step farther, we could write `example.ptr->ptr->ptr`, *or* 
`(*(*example.ptr).ptr).ptr`:

```
example.ptr
example.ptr->ptr
(*example.ptr).ptr
example.ptr->ptr->ptr
(*(*example.ptr).ptr).ptr
```

Since `test` is already type `nodeT *`, it's a little more straightforward:

```
test1->ptr
(*test1).ptr
test1->ptr->ptr
(*(*test).ptr).ptr
test1->ptr->ptr->ptr
(*(*(*test1).ptr).ptr).ptr
```

And finally, `test2`:

```
(*test2)->ptr
(**test2).ptr
(*test2)->ptr->ptr
(*(**test2).ptr).ptr
(*test2)->ptr->ptr->ptr
(*(*(**test2).ptr).ptr).ptr
```

Answer (score 4):

`test->ptr` is the same that `(*test).ptr`

So, I think you want `&(test->ptr)` (I am not sure of which operator has more priority).

Comment: Don't know why anyone would downvote this, to I'm restoring the balance.

Comment: Unless I was doing something wrong I tried the syntax you suggest. Perhaps I did make a mistake then.

Comment: What do you want to acces? If you want to access a member of `ptr`, then what you need is `(test->ptr)->member` (probably `test->ptr->member` would work too.

Comment: `->` has a higher precedence

Comment: This is correct; `(*ptr)` dereferences a pointer. `&var` gets a pointer to the variable. So `&(*ptr)` is effectively getting the address of the object pointed to by the pointer, i.e. the pointer. So `ptr->` is the same as `&(*ptr)->`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `test` is a pointer, you can't access it's fields using the `.` operator, you have to first dereference the pointer to get the struct directly:

`*test`

After that, you can access the field with the `.` operator:

`(*test).ptr`

The `->` operator is a shortcut to dereferencing the struct pointer:

`test->ptr`

That will get the ptr variable, just like the last expression. If what you want it the address pointed by ptr, then you are set.

If you want the address of the ptr variable, then you'll need to get its address by using the `&`:

`(&test)->ptr`

or

`&(*test).ptr`

Comment: `*test.ptr` is not valid syntax

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
nodeT n0 = { 0 };
nodeT n1 = { &n0 };

nodeT *test = &n1;
```

You can use:

```
test           // Pointer to n1
&test          // Pointer to test itself
test->ptr      // Pointer to n0
(*test).ptr    // Same as test->ptr
&test->ptr     // Pointer to the element of n1 (same as n1 because of the struct def'n
test->ptr->ptr // Pointer to null
```

Etc.

For example:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct nodeT nodeT;
struct nodeT { nodeT *ptr; };

static void print_addr(char * const tag, void *addr)
{
    printf("%-15s = %p\n", tag, addr);
}

int main(void)
{
    nodeT n0 = { 0 };
    nodeT n1 = { &n0 };
    nodeT *test = &n1;

    print_addr("test", test);
    print_addr("&test", &test);
    print_addr("test->ptr", test->ptr);
    print_addr("(*test).ptr", (*test).ptr);
    print_addr("&test->ptr", &test->ptr);
    print_addr("test->ptr->ptr", test->ptr->ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
test            = 0x7fff58829b10
&test           = 0x7fff58829b20
test->ptr       = 0x7fff58829b00
(*test).ptr     = 0x7fff58829b00
&test->ptr      = 0x7fff58829b10
test->ptr->ptr  = 0x0
```