# How does a pointer to a struct type behave?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a question. Let's say that I have a struct, say something like:

```
struct myData
{
    int a;
    int b
} x, y ;
```

Then, I create a pointer that points to x, for example:

```
myData * x_ptr = &x;
```

So I know that x_ptr point to the memory location where x is stored. So I can find the memory location for the whole struct. But, let's say I want to find the memory location for the member a of the struct variable x. How do I do that ?

For me, it would seem natural to do something like this:

```
x_ptr.a
```

Now, I know that this dosen't work. When I imagine how the variables are stored in the memory of the computer I'm thinking of a box with something in it. So for a struct, it would be a bigger box which contains two members, in my case **a** and **b**. So, is the memory location of **a** and **b** the same as the memory location for the whole "box" ? 
That's why I can't acces the memory location of x.a ?

I'm trying to understand pointers, and I quickly gained an idea of how things work, but this bothers me. Could somebody answer me, please ? Thank you! :)

Comment: `x_ptr->a` is the correct syntax in C++.

Comment: You can read about the historical backgrounds of `->` in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13366083/420683).

Comment: In this case, the address of `x` is also required to be the address of `x.a`. No padding is allowed before the first element of a struct, and a pointer to a struct, suitably converted, must also be a pointer to the first element of that struct.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple

the memory location of a is `&x_ptr->a;`

Answer (score 0):

```
int *x_a_ptr = &(x_ptr->a);
```

Now `x_a_ptr` is a pointer to the `a` that is part of the struct that `x_ptr` points to.

I think it's probably likely that in this case the value of `x_ptr` and `x_a_ptr` might be the same.  But if you got a pointer to `b`, it'd have a value different from `x_ptr`.

And by the way, instead of `&(x_ptr->a)`, you could just do `&(x.a)`.

Answer (score 0):

For POD types (POD means Plain Old Data), `struct` members are usually laid out linearly in memory, sometimes with padding between members to meet the alignment constraints of the types.

In your example, `x_ptr` points to the first byte of the `struct`, as well as the first member of the `struct`.  Indeed, you're allowed do convert a pointer-to-struct to pointer-to-first-member-of-struct safely.

Under the hood, when you say `x_ptr->a` or `x_ptr->b`, the compiler adds an offset to the pointer before dereferencing it, based on the layout of the `struct`.

You can get a direct pointer to a member of a `struct` by saying `&(x.a)` or `&(x.b)`.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for classes and structs regarding their memory structure is fairly straight-foward:

```
myData * x_ptr = &x; // pointer to x
x_ptr->a = 5; // sets a to 5
int* a = (int*)&x; // since a is the first element, this will set a to the address of x.a
int* b = &(x.a); // this will also give you the address of x.a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the address of a subobject, you can just take the address of the subobject, e.g.:

```
&x.a
```

or

```
&x_ptr->a
```

If you want to take sort of the address of `a` relative to a pointer, you could use

```
int myData::*a_ptr = &myData::a;
```

This defines a *pointer-to-member* which can be used with an object or a pointer to access the member, e.g.

```
int val0 = x.*a_ptr;
int val1 = x_ptr->*a_ptr;
```

If these don't make any sense just ignore pointer-to-members for now (they show up rarely in real-life, partly because hardly any C++ programmer knows about them).

Answer (score 0):

As said by others it is `&(x_ptr->a)`. To explain what's going on, you have to understand whether an expression is a pointer or not, and how to move between the two. Here are a few example to get some intuition:

```
myData dataOnStack; // dataOnStack lives on the stack
int a = dataOnStack.a; // we can directly reach for members

// this is just a pointer to struct we made earlier
myData * dataPtr = &onStack;

// here we dereference the pointer, and copy to the stack
myData copyOnStack = *dataPtr;

// again we can directly reach inside our copy
a = copyOnStack.a

// given a pointer, we can dereference and reach inside it using ->
// here, the whole expression dataPtr->a is not a pointer, because
// we have dereferenced dataPtr.
a = dataPtr->a;

// to finally answer your question, we can move back to the "pointer world"
// by taking the address of the previous expression
int* aPtr = &(dataPtr->a);

// alternatively, instead of going through the pointer, since
// we have the original struct on the stack we can just do this:
aPtr = &dataOnStack.a;
```