# Difference between dereferencing and component selection

Tags: c, pointers

In my sample code below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>    
int main()
{

  typedef struct {float x; float y;}C;

  C z;

  z.x=4;
  z.y=6;

  C *zpt=&z;

  *zpt.x;

  printf("%f",(*zpt).x);
}
```

I know `(*zpt).x` or `zpt->x` is used to dereference the pointer. But I get an error when I use `*zpt.x`, Error - "request for member 'x' in something not a structure or union". Can someone explain what does `*zpt.x` do? Is this an valid syntax and if yes, where and how it should be used?

Comment: You get an error? Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get is this:

`error: request for member ‘x’ in something not a structure or union`

As the compiler informs you, `zpt` is neither a structure or a union. The problem is that precedence of the dot operator (`.`) is higher than the one of the asterisk (`*`), thus the dot is enabled first and as a result you get the error, since the compiler reads this as: `*(zpt.x)`.

From [C Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

> Precedence 1: .              Structure and union member access
>
> Precedence 2: *              Indirection (dereference)

Putting parentheses makes clear how you want the operators to work, so

```
(*zpt).x
```

will work just fine, but you will receive a warning like this:

`warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]`

because you don't do anything, but I know this is just test code.

---

I would suggest reading the relevant question:

[Why does the arrow (->) operator in C exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366083/why-does-the-arrow-operator-in-c-exist)

Answer (score 4):

this goes wrong `*zpt.x;`

becuase it is interpreted as

```
*(zpt.x)
```

which has no meaning. First there is no zpt.x, second even if that was a float somehow you can't use * on a float

this is why the -> operator exists:  `zpt->x` is the same as `(*zpt).x` but easier to read and type