# difference between -> operator and the pointer * (c++)

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, dereference

i know that `->` operator can be a pointer to the direction of the variable, but why use it when you have `*` pointer operator, what is the difference, and can i prefer one over the other? for example:

```
a*b
```

means a is pointer to b (right? i could be mistaken forgive me because i'm a beginner)

is it equivalent to `a->b` ?

and `a<-b` meaning b is a pointer to a?

if so, is it possible to rely on `->` because it's simpler?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what `->` means. It doesn't mean any direction, it's just shorthand for dereferencing a pointer to a structure followed by structure member access. For a pointer to a structure `a` and member `b`, the expression `a->b` is equal to `(*a).b`. ***Also*** the `->` operator used to mean something else early on in the C language (where it comes from). Read e.g. [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13366168/440558) for more details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6586248/6543574 here it is explained, hope that helps :)

Comment: `a*b` _never_ means that `a` is a pointer to `b`. Closest possible meaning is that, as part of a declaration, it means that `b` is a pointer to an `a` (where `a` is a _type_). In expressions, `a*b` invokes multiplication.

Comment: my apologized, but how is it a regular point for a to b is written? i know that a &b possibly means that b us an alias for a (reference)

Comment: @AhmedDhia `int *a = &b;`

Comment: The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 2):

`a*b` usually means "multiply `a` and `b`". C++ has only very few lexical elements, and many of them serve many different purposes, so context is important.

`a->b` is member access and corresponds to `(*a).b`, i.e. access the `b` member of the value pointed to by `a`.

Note that both the `*` and the `->` operators can be overloaded.

Comment: i was going to make it a *b, for example int a *b

Comment: You mean `int a, *b;`?

Comment: @AhmedDhia: C++ is whitespace insensitive.

Comment: "You mean int a, *b;? " 
yes, i was trying to figure out how to make a pointer from a to b, i usually confuse it with multiplication and other uses for *
:)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it seems that you have confusion about what a pointer does, and where `*` belongs.
Pointer is a special type of object that points **to** another object, not **from** an object.
Pointer can be declared like this:

```
int *a;
```

Here, `*` specifies that `a` is a pointer. Pointer types are distinct type from the type of the object that they point to.
But what `a` points to is indeterminate. You need to assign an **address** to make `a` point to something. To do that, let's make an integer (here initialized with value `2`):

```
int b = 2;
```

And let `a` point to `b`:

```
a = &b;
```

Here, the unary `&` operator is used to take `b`'s **address**. And you assign this to `a`, and then `a` points to `b`.
Of course, a pointer can also be initialized. The statements above can be replaced to:

```
int b = 2;
int *a = &b;
```

Then, how do you get `b`'s value from `a`? You can do that by **dereferencing** `a`:

```
std::cout << *a << std::endl;
```

This prints `2`. The unary operator `*` is used here to **dereference** `a`. This `*` is different from the `*` used to declare `a` above and should not be confused.

```
++*a;
```

This increases `b`. `b` now has value `3`.
You can make `a` point to a different object by assigning another address:

```
int c = 3;
a = &c;
```

Now `a` points to `c` instead of `b`.
You can copy a pointer, which will point to the same object:

```
int *d = a;
```

Now `d` points to `c`, which `a` also points to.

References are different from pointers:

```
int &e = b;
```

`&` is used here to specify `e` is a reference. This `&` is different from the `&` used to take an address and should not be confused. Here, `e` **refers** to `b`.
They **refer** to an object and always act as if they were that object:

```
++e;
```

This increases `b`. `b` now has value `4`.
Unlike pointers, references must always refer to an object:

```
int &f; // error
```

A reference can also refer to a pointer:

```
int *&g = a;
```

`g` refers to `a`.
But a pointer cannot point to a reference:

```
int &*h = &e; // error
```

Comment: Thanks alot :) this got things clearly, one question though, how do i prevent the output from printing the memory address or location of a pointer?

Comment: You should just not give a memory address to output streams. Following the examples above, `std::cout << d << std::endl` will output `c`'s address.