# Why are the 'dereference' and the 'address of' operators on the left?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, dereference, operator-precedence

In C (and some other C-like languages) we have 2 unary operators for working with pointers: the dereference operator (`*`) and the 'address of' operator (`&`). They are *left* unary operators, which introduces an uncertainty in order of operations, for example:

```
*ptr->field
```

or

```
*arr[id]
```

The order of operations *is* strictly defined by the standard, but from a human perspective, it is confusing. If the `*` operator was a *right* unary operator, the order would be obvious and wouldn't require extra parentheses:

```
ptr*->field vs ptr->field*
```

and

```
arr*[id] vs arr[id]*
```

So is there a good reason why are the operators *left* unary, instead of right. One thing that comes to mind would be the declaration of types. Left operators stay near the type name (`char *a` vs `char a*`), but there are type declarations, which already break this rule, so why bother (`char a[num]`, `char (*a)(char)`, etc).

Obviously, there are some problems with this approach too, like the

```
 val*=2
```

Which would be either an `*=` short hand for `val = val * 2` or dereference and assign `val* = 2`.
However this can be easily solved by requiring a white space between the `*` and `=` tokens in case of dereferencing. Once again, nothing groundbreaking, since there is a precedent of such a rule (`- -a` vs `--a`).

So why are they left instead of right operators?

Edit:
I want to point out, that I asked this question, because many of the weirder aspects of C have interesting explanations, for why they are the way they are, like the [existence of the `->` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366083/why-does-the-arrow-operator-in-c-exist) or the type declarations or the indexing starting from 0. And so on. The reasons may be no longer valid, but they are still interesting in my opinion.

Comment: You want to rewrite C syntax?

Comment: @WeatherVane I am asking, if there is a reason for the syntax being the way it is.

Comment: It has been developed for donkeys years.

Comment: @RuRo: Undoubtedly there is a reason :) But it might be just the preferences of the people who originally created the language.

Comment: The probable culprit has been dead for 6 years, R.I.P.

Comment: Questions of the type "why designers of this language decided to use this syntax and not this other equally possible syntax" are unanswerable.

Comment: @n.m. I disagree. The choices made by language creators are not purely random. For example, the rationale for why types are decalred like `char *a` is because the creators of the language believed, that declaration should reflect the use-case. This is fairly logical. *A lot* of thought goes into creating a language, why not consider that it was deliberate?

Comment: @n.m They might well be off topic for Stack Overflow, but with mailing list archives,  committee reports, etc., these kinds of questions are often answerable.

Comment: BTW, I understand, that the question may be historical and as such not very StackOverflow-ish, but it is definitely not 'opinion' based save for the opinion of K&R.

Comment: I found the authoritative source. No longer opinion-based.

Comment: @n.m. they're very much answerable if you can quote the designers verbatim.

Comment: what is more interesting is that **[tag:D]** decided to go for *prefix*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There indeed *is* an authoritative source: ["The Development of the C Language" by the creator of the language, Dennis M. Ritchie](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html):

> An accident of syntax contributed to the perceived complexity of the language. The indirection operator, spelled `*` in C, is syntactically a unary prefix operator, **just as in BCPL and B**. This works well in simple expressions, but in more complex cases, parentheses are required to direct the parsing. For example, to distinguish indirection through the value returned by a function from calling a function designated by a pointer, one writes `*fp()` and `(*pf)()` respectively. The style used in expressions carries through to declarations, so the names might be declared
>
> ```
> int *fp();
> int (*pf)();
> ```
>
> In more ornate but still realistic cases, things become worse:
>
> ```
> int *(*pfp)();
> ```
>
> is a pointer to a function returning a pointer to an integer. There are two effects occurring. Most important, C has a relatively rich set of ways of describing types (compared, say, with Pascal). Declarations in languages as expressive as C—Algol 68, for example—describe objects equally hard to understand, simply because the objects themselves are complex. A second effect owes to details of the syntax. Declarations in C must be read in an `inside-out' style that many find difficult to grasp [[Anderson 80](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=947627)]. **Sethi [[Sethi 81](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/spe.4380110606/full)] observed that many of the nested declarations and expressions would become simpler if the indirection operator had been taken as a postfix operator instead of prefix, but *by then it was too late to change.***

---

Thus the reason why `*` is on the left in **C** is because it was [on the left in **B**](https://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/b/manu/manu.html#Section6_3).

**B** was partially based on [BCPL](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/clive-on-bcpl.html), where the dereferencing operator was `!`.
This was on the left; the binary `!` was an *array indexing* operator:

> `a!b`
>
> is equivalent to `!(a+b)`.
>
> `!a`
>
> is the content of the cell whose address is given by a; it can appear on the left of an assignment.

Yet the 50 year old [BCPL](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/bcpl.html) manual doesn't even contain mentions of the `!` operator - instead, the operators were words: unary `lv` and `rv`. Since these were understood as if they were functions, it was natural that they preceded the operand; later the longish `rv a` could then be replaced with syntactic sugar `!a`.

---

Many of the current C operator practices can be traced via this route. B alike had `a[b]` being equivalent to `*(a + b)` to `*(b + a)` to `b[a]` just like in BCPL one could use `a!b` <=> `b!a`.

Notice that in B variables were *untyped*, so certainly similarity with declarations could not have been the reason to use `*` on the left there.

So the reason for unary `*` being on the left in C is as boring as *"there wasn't any problem in the simpler programs with the unary `*` being on the left, in the position that everyone was accustomed to have the dereferencing operator in other languages, that no one really thought that some other way would have been better until it was too late to change it"*.

Comment: Note the syntax for "=+" and "=*" was changed to "+=" and "*=". Also white space is needed for dereferencing after a divide: "/ *ptr2var" versus "/*ptr2var" (this would be the start of a comment).

Comment: "Too late for a change" it might indeed have been, but C has experienced syntax additions over the time. Thus, it might have been easy to just add another operator which operated the way the other did, but in a postfix way. Bit it wasn't probably worth the effort.

Comment: @glglgl well, dmr himself considered it "too late"; and ANSI and then ISO committees were conservative in their approaches.

Comment: If variables are untyped there'd be an ambiguity `b * + 2`  is that `b` multiplied by `+2`, or dereferenced-b plus 2 ?

Comment: @M.M that is true, but then the choice of `*` is pretty arbitrary here anyway.