# In C, why were two different operators (. and ->) defined to work with structures?

Tags: c

Let's be clear:

**I know the difference between the . and the -> operators**

When working with a structure, the . operator is a simple offset added to the address of the structure. When working with a pointer to a structure, the -> operator first dereferences the pointer and then adds the offset.

My question is: **Why were two operators introduced in the first place?**

The compiler obviously knows whether I'm working with a structure or with a pointer to a structure, so it shouldn't require me to use the proper operator. With the single . operator, it could dereference the pointer by itself first **if** working with a pointer to a structure.

I ask myself this question every single time I use the improper operator, and I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366083) seems like a better duplicate target to me.

Comment: nice find, added