# Using dot operator vs arrow operator with string pointer in structs

Tags: c

Q1: I'm trying to understand why in this code I'm supposed to use a dot operator when calling the string pointer rather than an arrow which is used for pointers.

Q2: If I was trying to initialize age would I use the dot operator?

```
typedef struct Person 
{
  char *name;
  int age;

} Person;

Person* deletePerson(Person *person, int totalPeople) 
{
     int i;

     for(i=0; i<totalPeople; i++) 
     {
     free(person[i].name); 
     free(person); 
     }

     return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The only thing one needs to know about it is that `a->b` is the same as `(*a).b` and the same as `a[0].b`.

Comment: `person` is, depending on how you think about it, either an array of `struct Person`, or a pointer to `struct Person`.  So `person[0]` is a `struct Person`.  Since it's a struct (*not* a pointer-to-strut), you use `.` on it.

Comment: There's something else wrong with this code: `free(person)` is almost certainly wrong, and especially so given that it's in the loop.

Comment: It depends on what's on the LHS of the operand.  You use `pointer->age` or `structure.age`.  `person[i]` is a structure; use `person[i].age`.  `person` alone is a pointer; use `person->age`.

Comment: In answer to your other question, you would access `age` the same way you access `name`: perhaps as `person[i].age`.  And, in fact, to confirm what's going on, you might want to print out `person[i].name` and `person[i].age` as you free them.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add free(person) outside the for loop!

Comment: The name of the variable is semantically wrong. It should be `persons` or `people`...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: But `person[i]` reads better than `persons[i]`.

Comment: @ScottHunter that is true... but there is no justification for the function name. Nor for the return value

Comment: Why you need the loop? If you already have the person pointer you can just `free(person->name); free(person);`

Comment: Related/Duplicate [Why does the arrow (->) operator in C exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366083/why-does-the-arrow-operator-in-c-exist)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here `person[i].name`will throw error

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the arrow `->` operator when you have a pointer to a struct (or union) **on the left**, and the dot `.` operator when you have a struct on the left. It doesn't depend on what's on the right.

If `person` was a pointer to a single `Person`, to access its field, you'd use `person->name` and `person->age`.

But here `person` is evidently a pointer to the first element of an array of `Person`. (A pointer to the first element is how arrays are passed around in C.) To access an individual element of the array, you use the subscript operator (square brackets `[…]`): `person[i]`. `person[i]` is the element with index `i`, not a pointer to the element with index `i`. Since `person[i]` is a struct, you use the dot operator to access its fields.

---

In addition, as others have already remarked, `free(person);` inside the loop doesn't make sense. You'd free the whole array as soon as you've processed the first element. Call `free(person)` after the loop, once you've finished cleaning up all the elements of the array (assuming that `person` was allocated with `malloc`).

Answer (score 1):

`person->name` would be synonymous with `person[0].name`; since you want to refer to the name of an arbitrary `person`, you couldn't use `->` this way.

(I suppose you would use `(person+i)->name`, but your original code is clearer, IMHO.)

As for initializing `age`: what else would you use other than `.`?

P.S. `free`ing `person` inside the loop means a) you free it multiple times, and b) `person[i]` will be a problem after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function is invalid and has a bug.

I think you mean

```
Person* deletePerson(Person *person, int totalPeople) 
{
     for ( int i=0; i < totalPeople; i++ ) 
     {
         free( person[i].name ); 
         free( person[i] ); 
     }

     free( person );

     return NULL;
}
```

This statement

```
free(person[i].name);
```

can be equivalently rewriten like

```
free( ( person + i )->name );
```

or even like

```
free( ( *( person + i ) ).name );
```

However the first statement is more readable.

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is that **E1[E2] is identical
>   to (*((E1)+(E2)))**. Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Answer (score 0):

In C, the -> operator is a cosmetic substitute for (*var).field,
and the [ ] is a substitute for *(ptr + n).

In your code, the line:

```
free(person[i].name);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
free((*(person + i)).name)
```

If you use -> instead of the dot operator that would be wrong.
I can see why you are confused, to make it look simpler, the function parameter “Person *person” is basically an array of struct Person, equivalent to “Person person[]”.
If you were to access only the first Person in the array you could have used person->name which is the same as person[0].name