# Why I should use '->' instead of '.' in a pointer of the object?

Tags: c++, pointers, dot-operator

I agree this might be a very beginner's question, but I have no idea why I can't use '.' to access a member of a pointer to an object.

e.g.

```
JMP *sum_obj = new JMP("0");
JMP a;
sum_obj->number;
a.number;

sum_obj.number; // error: request for member ‘number’ in ‘sum_obj’, which is of pointer type ‘JMP*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
```

Here, why should I use `->` for the `sum_obj` `number` member?

Comment: Since in C there are pointers and values so to operators are used to distinguish those too. In other languages like Java you have just references. C++ leverage this duplication of this access operators and provides smart pointers (value which has some properties accessible by `.` and and pointed value accessible by `->`).

Comment: Because its a pointer. Because the designers of the language said so.

Comment: Because `sum_obj`  is a pointer. `x->y`  is the same as `(*x).y`. I suggest you read the chapter dealing with pointers in your beginner's C++ text book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C there would be no technical reason. A non-technical reason is clarity - if you see a `->`, you know that it's a pointer and can potentially be null, so you might need to check for null before dereferencing it.

In C++, there are classes that pretend to be pointers to some degree (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::optional`). They support `*` and `->` like pointers, but they also have their own member functions, accessible with `.`. Separating the notation this way avoids any possible member name conflicts, and also adds clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your good explanation. Now I know why I should use `->` instead of `.`.

Comment: Good answer. However note how the OP got an error for trying to call dot operator on a pointer. You left out that `p->x` is identical to `(*p).x` (as mentioned in the comments). It seems your answer could use one introductory sentence.

Comment: @Friedrich They seem to already know about `->`, as they mention it in the question. To me it reads like a question about why the language was designed this way.

Comment: Agreed. Do they know about `(*p).x`?

Answer (score 0):

the arrow operator `->` is used to access the member variables or member functions of an object that is pointed to by a pointer. The arrow operator is used with pointers because when we use the dot operator `.` to access a member variable or function, the compiler will assume that we are accessing a member of an object, not a pointer to an object.